# Lync 2013 VPN access

Tags: vpn, lync, lync-2013

I have a working, internal use only Lync 2013 Enterprise FE pool.

Is an Edge server required to expand access to VPN users (no split tunnel, and with double encryption of course), or would a reverse proxy with port translation be sufficient?

Comment: If your VPN users do not split-tunnel and appear as normal internal users and normal internal access is working properly, why would you need an edge pool? What issues have you encountered when you tried to pilot this?

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean Proxy or Reverse Proxy ? Nevermind...

Neither an Edge Server nor a (Reverse)Proxy are required to access Lync through VPN.
These are only required to access Lync from outside your LAN (external users and federation). VPN users are *virtually* in your LAN.

If you have a firewall between your LAN and your VPN subnet, just ensure to open ports but this does not require any port translation.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you even need an edge server then.
You may need to specify the server name manually, and the users need to trust your CA if you used an internal one.

It's not pretty with the double encryption, but it should work.